# Using SAGA GIS 7.X modules in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

Is it possible (and how) to use the SAGA GIS 7.x modules in QGIS (as well as for GRASS GIS)?

Answer (score 2):

The inbuilt saga tool is locked to Saga's "long term support" release, which is stuck at 2.3.

Try the "saga Nextgen" plugin from the qgis plugins repo - it allows newer saga versions to be used (although with zero support, and a good chance of breakage!)

Answer (score 0):

+/- one year later :
QGIS LTR now needs proj6 whereas SAGA needs to provide PROJ <= 5.x. SAGA 2 will not get support to PROJ 6.